# How To Print All Values In An Object If A Certain Name/Value pair exists?

Tags: python

So I'm fairly new to Python and development in general. So what I'm trying to do is print all the values in an object if the name/value pair "oranges: "555555" exists. I've listed my request results below and the code that I currently have running.

```
query_response = requests.get(GET_URL, headers=GIT_HEADERS) 
jsonResults = query_response.json()
```

This returns results like so

```
 [
    {
        "oranges": "555555",
        "from": "California"
        "actor": "Tom Brady",
        "action": "wins_all_superbowls"
        "repo": "Love_Snow_Mountains",
        "repo_id": 66666,
        "org_id": 85555
        "@timestamp": 1666646455465,
        "business_id": 454545,
        "actor_location": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 0.0,
                "lon": 0.0
            }
        }
]
```

Here's the code that I currently have:

```
if (obj['oranges'] == '555555' for obj in jsonResults):
print(vars(object)) //this is the part that I'm stuck at
```

So if `"oranges" : "555555"` exists in an array, I want to print all the other values and then throw them into a row in a csv file. I think I can figure out the row and csv stuff but I just want to be able to print all those other values if "oranges" : "555555" does exists.

Comment: In list comprehension the if condition is to the right of for loop 
`result = [obj for obj in jsonResults if obj['oranges'] == '555555' ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate with a `for`, and filter with an `if`

```
for_csv = []
for obj in jsonResults:
    if obj['oranges'] == '555555':
        for_csv.append(obj)
        for k, v in obj.items():
            print(f"{k}={v}")
```

---

For the CSV output, you'll need to handle multilevel dict at `actor_location`

Comment: Thank you soooo much :)

Comment: Hey I had a question about this. On the line "for_csv.append(obj)" whats going on here? Are we just appending all the "oranges" objects into for_csv = [] ?

`for_csv.append(obj)
        for k, v in obj.items():
            print(f"{k}={v}")`

Also on the last line, what {k}={v} mean? I know that the "f" does but I can't seem to figure out what the `=` means. Thanks!

@azro

Answer (score 0):

You're very close; you want to use the `any` function:

```
if any(obj['oranges'] == '555555' for obj in jsonResults):
    print(jsonResults)
```

The expression `obj['oranges'] == '555555' for obj in jsonResults` is a generator that produces a `True` or `False` value for each `obj` in `jsonResults`.  The `any` function will go through that generator and tell you whether *any* of those values are `True`.

Comment: You may also want to answer the actual question of the user ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's better you use `get` method, so you don't get an error if the dictionary key you are requesting doesn't exist.

```
if any(obj.get("oranges") == '555555' for obj in jsonResults):
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to take a look at this with me :)